# Using SLF4J, is it possible to act on errors/warnings?

Tags: java, logging, logback, slf4j

I have a java OSGi server application and would like to abort the boot process if an error or warning happens/happened.

If some warnings should not abort the process I could set the logger to `error`:

```
<logger name="LOGGER"><level value="error"/></logger>
```

Maybe there is a listener or API to scan existing log entries?

I think I could implement my own `appender` but maybe there is an easier/cleaner way?

Comment: SLF4J is a facade for logging frameworks, it is not designed for modifying the behaviour of the program in case a (specific kind of) error occurs. Don't try to do something like that with an appender, you'll end up with an ugly and strange solution. Just add the appropriate error handling to the code of your application itself.

Comment: ok makes sense, just thought it would be a great place to hook-in. Since third party OSGi bundles might throw errors/warnings which I'm not able to handle.

Comment: To handle errors from those third-party bundles, you could create your own bundle which depends on the third-party bundles and which checks that the third-party ones have started or at least are in a state where they are usable by your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Logback, you can implement a `TurboFilter` that analyses all the log events and does whatever you want when a message of a particular level is emitted. You can find details in the [docs on TurboFilters](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html#TurboFilter).

Comment: Is there a way to remove or stop the filter at some point (e.g. after the server is started)? stop() does not work.

Comment: `stop()` will only work if it's implemented by the particular filter it's called on. But filters cannot be removed completely, as far as I know. In you implementation, you can simply have a boolean volatile flag `active` and change it to `true` / `false` on `start()` / `stop()`. If it's `false`, just return `ACCEPT` from `decide()`, otherwise make your checks on the events.